# Bash arrays: Need help with white space

Tags: arrays, bash, whitespace

I'm trying to create an array in bash from a file with the following sample format:

```
data, data, interesting
data, data, more interesting
```

The way I'm populating the arrays:

```
read -r -a DATA1 <<< $(cat $FILE | awk -F, '{ print $1 }')
read -r -a DATA2 <<< $(cat $FILE | awk -F, '{ print $2 }')
read -r -a DATA3 <<< $(cat $FILE | awk -F, '{ print $3 }')
```

When I examine the array DATA3, there are 3 elements:

```
interesting
more
interesting
```

I need it to show only 2 elements like:

```
interesting
more interesting
```

How can I preserve the white space in field 3 so when I call that element from the array, it appears as "more interesting"? Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

The key is to use the `IFS` (internal field separators) variable together with `read`.

`read` can read words directly into an array using the `-a` option. Set `IFS=,` and it will split at comma:

```
while read f; do
    echo "$f" | (IFS=, && read -a arr && echo ${arr[2]})
done
```

will echo

```
interesting
 more interesting
```

You can also read directly into variable names:

```
IFS=, && read f1 f2 f2
```

EDIT: I can recommend reading [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

Answer (score 1):

Use `cut`. Example:

```
read -r -a DATA1 <<< $(cut -d, -f 1 $FILE)
read -r -a DATA2 <<< $(cut -d, -f 2 $FILE)
read -r -a DATA3 <<< $(cut -d, -f 3 $FILE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IFS=','
while read -a array
do
    echo "${array[2]}" 
done < data.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>> Is there a better way to handle this? - Tee Bone

$ awk -F", " '{print $3}' file
interesting
more interesting
```